# all option breaks xy package

Tags: xy-pic, bugs

I've been trying to load [`xy`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xypic?lang=en) with the `all` option, but I get the error

```
! LaTeX Error: Two \documentclass or \documentstyle commands.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.1 \documentclass{
                   article}
?
```

This is the code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}

stuff

\end{document}
```

If I remove the `all` option it compiles just fine. Is this a bug? Or am I missing something

```
$ tex --version
TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2017/MacPorts 2017_2)
kpathsea version 6.2.3
Copyright 2017 D.E. Knuth
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not call your test document `xy.tex` or you end up recursively inputting the same file and generating errors.

Note that the log file shows the problem in the part that you did not show:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./xy.tex
```

...............

```
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xypic/xy.sty (./xy.tex
```

..................................................................................................!!!!!!!!!

```
! LaTeX Error: Two \documentclass or \documentstyle commands.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.1 \documentclass{
                   article}
?
```

Comment: I was calling it `xy<something>.tex`, but you're right. That was the problem